# Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '3.2.3'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: spring-boot, gradle-plugin

I have just downloaded a spring-boot project from http://start.spring.io/.
The error is occurring in the build.gradle file:

```
> Build file 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\WorkSpace\myProject\build.gradle' line: 3

Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '3.2.3'] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
```

I tried to build the project with an older SB version but the error persists.

Comment: Please share the complete `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` files for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added the Spring Boot plugin to your **build.gradle** file.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}
```

Open terminal from your IDE (I used IntelliJ IDEA) and type following command:

```
./gradlew build
```

**This command will generate executable archive placed under build/libs directory.**

That's it. Now click **run** button and enjoy with your code.

Comment: Thank you, I've already solved the problem, as I mentioned in earlier answer.
Anyway, the cmd ./gradlew clean build didn't work in my case due to artifacts configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after verifying the artifacts configuration in "**.gradle**" home directory folder.
For those who have specific artifacts configuration related to enterprise environment, you can simply comment the `systemProp.https.proxyHost` in gradle properties.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).